# LuaLaTeX — too high memory usage

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, luatex, memory

I've recently made my project buildable under `LuaLaTeX`.

This is a bibliography database project which uses `biblatex` and `biber` to compile the database to produce something about 66-paged pdf file.

Now I'm experience some problems with memory usage: while I was using `pdflatex` memory usage was about 100M which is affordable, but with LuaLaTeX memory usage grows too fast (for the last time I've killed `lualatex.exe` when it was using 2G of RAM.

Here is the some suspicious output:

> can't allocate 402653184 bytes

I wonder if this is OK and WHY is this OK.

I can provide sources, if this is going to help.

UPDATE: the problem may be with polyglossia, since I use `babel` under `pdflatex` and `polyglossia` undex `lualatex`.

UPDATE: I was able to compile my project with biblatex + polyglossia + lualatex. Here is the log: https://gist.github.com/georgthegreat/7386134

Comment: 2GiB for a 66 page file seems quite exaggerated. ;-) I suspect some loop.

Comment: Which version of lua(la)tex are you using? (This information should be contained in the first line of the .log file.) There was a memory leak issue in the version of lualatex that came before version 0.76. Running lualatex repeatedly might cause the system to run out of RAM...

Comment: This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013062821 (rev 4627) — all packages are of the latest version available on CTAN.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to add that I'm using 64-bit Miktex on 64-bit Win7.

Comment: Can you show a minimal example?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure what causes such a error. Using a minimal example works fine — e.g. lualatex + polyglossia working fine. But, when I try to compile a huge project, everything crashes.

Comment: Does the leak occur when running ``luaotfload-tool -uf`` as well?
The font index is rebuilt while compiling a document under some circumstances, and depending on the fonts on your machine it can eat tons of memory.

Comment: I've ran the command above. Memory usage was about 1.2 GB (at the top), but I'm not sure if this is the reason.

Comment: @Georg This rules out one class of causes. What changes did you make to the document since it now compiles?

Comment: @phg the problem is that I'm not sure what makes it compile, and what makes it fail. Sometimes removing all temporary stuff (*.run.xml, *.aux, etc.) helps, but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @Georg In that case I have no advice to offer besides platitudes: clone the code and bisect until memory consumption drops. Without a concrete test document there isn’t much hope for remote help, sorry.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: With no MWE, we can't hope to answer here, sorry.

Comment: Joseph, after recent updates memory usage seems to have decreased.